# My setInterval function isn't working at all, Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am a fairly new programmer, and currently am trying to understand OOP from the JS side of things. I have some pretty basic code for a flashing cursor, yet for some reason it isnt working. The page loads, and the cursor just appears onscreen with no changing. The code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Cursor</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

var str = null;
var counter = 0;

var flipFlop = function() {
alert("working");
if(counter === 0) {
document.getElementbyId('console').style.visibility='visible';
counter = 1;

}
else if(counter === 1) {
document.getElementbyId('console').style.visibility='hidden';
counter = 0;
}
else {
//debug alert
alert("function broken.");
}
};
var setIntOnload = function() {
setInterval(function() {
flipFlop();
}, 1000);
};
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setIntOnload()">
<div id="console">
  |
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure why this isnt working... Help would be appreciated :)
PS First Post :D

Comment: You have typo. There is no getElementbyId method. It should be getElementById()

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code. Use `getElementById` instead of `getElementbyId`. JavaScript variable names (and methods) are case sensitive.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FcrQ7/

Always check your browser console in case something in your code is not working. You had the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getElementbyId'

Answer (score 0):

Its Working

Change `getElementById` instead of `getElementbyId`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rrmr/7/)

Comment: Just the same answer as above :)

Comment: so what bro the mistake is same so only